# Kitten suddenly won’t use litter tray

Tags: cats

I have had a kitten for over 3 weeks now he’s been perfect at using his litter tray and still using it however he is choosing to poo in another place too I have added another litter tray to the place he keeps going too now I’ve just found him in a different place weeing not far from the litter tray! It’s fresh litter every day I really do not know what to do!

Comment: often when a cat stops using the litterbox it is a sign of pain and possible urinary inffection or other problems when eliminating,so you have to take your cat to the vet if the vet finds your cat to be ok please add this information to your question it will be helpfull in finding the answer.but first take him to the vet.

Answer (score 2):

**Edit:** Trond Hansen is right - the problem could be health related, and sometimes it is hard to see it at first since cats like tend to hide their illnesses, so visiting a vet would be the best start before looking for other causes.

Besides urinary infection (which concerns rather urination) there could be other reasons:

- the litter tray could be too hard to access - it could be to high, some litter boxes have doors or covers that cats are afraid of..
- the litter tray could be to small to be comfortable
- the litter tray could be in a place that is not enough intimate, peaceful and the cat could be afraid of doing their things there
- the cat may not like the contents of the litter tray - if you use bentonite clay - try to change the size of the grains, usually the smaller grains are preferred
- if you use scented litter cats sometimes don't like it, also my cats didn't like the silicate litter
- check the surface on which your cat likes to poo, for instance my cat loved to urinate on paper or soft materials lying on the floor, you could try to fill the floor of your litter box with the same material
- constipation could be the reason - the cat can blame the litter tray for his problems

Comment: This does not explain why the cat was using litter tray fine earlier

Comment: as i mention in my comment to the question any illness have to be excluded before one starts speculating in other causes.so one need to go to the vet first.

Comment: @sonevol since it is a new cat, in the place where he was from he could have used another type of litter box, so when he saw this one in his new home, he continued to use it, but then it appeared that it is easier, better not to use it and use the floor instead

Answer (score 0):

You can try two things simultaneously.

1. Make the litter box more attractive

Try changing the litter type and use trial and error to find right litter. Make sure there is no source of noise nearby.

2. Make the unwanted sites repelling.

First use good cleaners to completely get rid of earlier poop smell. Then use cat repellents.

Also try making the use of litter boxes rewarding by offering treats when used.